# React different state properties getting bound

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a table in react where the user can edit individual rows by clicking the edit button  on a row and then submit once he has made his change. I have say two components  App.js and its child Table.js to implement this.

The way I thought of doing this initially was letting each of this component have their own state for rows and then the Table component reads from the  props send to it by parent initially  and only change the parent rows when users submits the change as oppose to onChange event. But I've read that reading props into state is an anti-pattern.

So decided to have everything in the parent by having two values for row (oldrows,newrows). And using them to maintain state instead, This is  the design I came up with :

[image]

But what happens is whenever I click cancel the oldRows get bound to the newRows, here is a codePen example I put up:

https://codepen.io/snedden-gonsalves/pen/zYOVMWz

```
handleChangeRowInput = (event, keyValue) => {
    let keyVals = [...this.state.newValuesArray];
    keyVals[this.state.editIndex][keyValue] = event.currentTarget.value;

    this.setState({
      newValuesArray: keyVals
    })
  }

    handleCancelRowInput = () => {
      this.setState({
        newValuesArray: [...this.state.oldValuesArray],
        editIndex: -1
      })
      console.log('array', this.state.newValuesArray)

  }

   handleSubmitRowInput = () => {
      this.setState({
        oldValuesArray: [...this.state.newValuesArray],
        editIndex: -1
      })
  }
```

In the codePen example if you enter a new value then cancel and then try adding a new value again the the old values and new values get bound.

I tried using lodash deepClone but it didn't work out, not sure why this is happening.

Also if you could comment on what is the best way to design this in react that would be awesome as I am very new to react and just trying to learn ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any issue after the cancel function. For me, the issue was coming up after I called the save function.

After clicking on the save button and then editing again, the old values and new values were get bound.

The `handleSubmitRowInput` function should create a new array for the oldValuesArray using the `cloneDeep` function

```
   handleSubmitRowInput = () => {
      this.setState({
        oldValuesArray: _.cloneDeep(this.state.newValuesArray),
        editIndex: -1
      })
  }
```

Comment: Yes looks like I wasn't using cloneDeep as I was suppose to, also there is an same issue with cancel if we do it twice, thanks for your response